# Opening phone network settings dialog from phonegap app

Tags: cordova, dialog, settings

When my phone (Android) is not connected to the internet and I open the browser app, it pops up a dialog that says:

> This application requires network access.
>   Enable mobile network or Wi-Fi to download data.

It then has two buttons - one for Settings and one for Cancel.

Pressing settings takes me directly to the "Wireless & networks" settings dialog.

I want to display a similar dialog from a phoneGap application. 
Can this be done?

Comment: nope, maybe today some plugin can be used to enable this functionality...

Comment: Hi I got some solution in GitHub for your problem please go through with the following below link hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Diagnostic plugin** for PhoneGap may give your answer.

Download the plugin from the following link: [Download Link](https://github.com/don/phonegap-plugins-1/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic)

Than go through the following steps:

1. Add the ***diagnostic.js*** file after the ***cordova.js*** in the html header part.

> < script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-X.X.X.js">< /script >
> < script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="diagnostic.js" > < /script >

2. Create a directory within your project called **src/net/avantic/diagnosticPlugin** and move ***Diagnostic.java*** into it.
3. In your **res/xml/plugins.xml** file add the following line:

> < plugin name="Diagnostic"
> value="net.avantic.diagnosticPlugin.Diagnostic"/>

4. And in the **AndroidManifest.xml** add:

> < uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
> <
> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

#### Than for calling the WIFI settings dialog you need add the following code wherever you want :

```
 //Check whether Wifi is enable or not...
 window.plugins.diagnostic.isWifiEnabled(wifiEnabledSuccessCallback, wifiEnabledErrorCallback);

 //If function success callback result is 0 it will open the wifi settings dialog box...
 function wifiEnabledSuccessCallback(result) {
      if (!result){
           alert("You must enable the Wi-Fi in device settings.");
           window.plugins.diagnostic.switchToWifiSettings();
        }
      else{
            alert("WiFi is ON!");
          }
     }

  function wifiEnabledErrorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Hope the above solution will work for you..

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LeftyX 2 I think you are right. I will update the details.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Though you can get it to install automatically and skip some of the steps above if you run `cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic`. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#android-and-ios